# Olson Time Zone Id to Windows Standard Format using Noda Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, timezone

The conversion between Olson and Windows time Id's has come up multiple times on SO; with many people suggesting Jon Skeet's [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) for this task.

Whilst the Google Code page states that there is a function to convert between the two, I can't find details anywhere of how to do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Haven't seen one in the code.  You can create `DateTimeZone` objects from either Olson ids or Windows TimeZoneInfo objects but can't convert AFAIK.

Comment: This can be done now with Noda Time 1.1.0.  [I have posted conversion functions here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824)

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately we don't have a mapping that way round (Windows to Olson) at the moment.

All of the "provider" interface is slightly up in the air right now:

- Even within the current code, there are API changes we want to make, partly to make code using it more testable
- The Unicode CLDR mappings have changed between 1.x and 2.x, so now there are multiple mappings each way, potentially (IIRC).

In other words: sorry, we don't support this at the moment, but we'll bear it in mind when trying to finalize the 1.0 API.

Answer (score 0):

`TzdbTimeZoneProvider` support conversion from Windows to Olson, but `BclTimeZoneProvider` (provider for windows time zones) does not have correct implementation of `MapTimeZoneId` method and interface seems wrong...

Here is implementation at `TzdbTimeZoneProvider`:

```
 public string MapTimeZoneId(TimeZoneInfo zone)
 {
   string str;
   this.windowsIdMap.TryGetValue(zone.Id, out str); 
   return str;
 }
```

Note: the windowsIdMap is a dictionary

Here is implementation at `BclTimeZoneProvider`:

```
public string MapTimeZoneId(TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
{
  return timeZone.Id;
}
```

Note: It just return id of windows time zone.

It seems more correct interface for this method will be:

```
 string MapTimeZoneId(string providerZoneId);
```

Then both implementations can be done correctly. I guess you can put this question at Noda Time google groups.

For now you can look into `TzdbTimeZoneProvider` to find way how to map from Olson to Windows tz (simple iteration through the windowsIdMap values).

Comment: The implementation is fine - the purpose of `MapTimeZoneId` is to map *from* Windows *to* the provider-specific ID. That's why it takes a `TimeZoneInfo` instead of a string.